# What manual switch do I need for multi power source system?

Tags: power, switches

I have a 20A DC device that I am powering from two different 12V DC sources and one AC 120V source (the AC source will drive a PS in the case to supply 12V DC) depending on availability:

- Internal Battery DC
- External Battery DC
- AC 120

So 3 power sources in, but the same feed line out to the device. I want a simple switch which doesn't need to maintain power between switchover—so completely disconnected from each source. I looked at a regular rotary switch but most don't handle 20A. Usually around an amp or two at most. Can you point me to a rotary that will work for this? I need 4 positions and 4 poles? (one position being "Off").

Comment: why do you need a 4 pole switch?

Comment: You should restate the question to ask "what kind of switches can fulfill this requirement" instead of "point me to a specific rotary switch." The latter formulation, as you have it now, will be closed as a product recommendation, which is off-topic.

Comment: Narrow it down from here:

https://www.alliedelec.com/relays/power-relays/?category=2%7C3882599%2F3886728&n8520=25%20A

You can do the same on the Digikey website as well.

Comment: Jsotola—I wanted to keep all sources totally separate so my my understanding was that it would require that. But I guess I could get away with three? What do you know that I should know but don't?

Comment: JYelton—So product recommendations are not allowed? I am a brand newbie (today) to SE.

Comment: Varun—thanks for answering the question—even though I should rewrite the question more toward the engineering of it.